# smartgwt dynamic listgrid with dynamic field

Tags: dynamic, field, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm on my smartgwt project with listgrid control. I want some dynamic mechanism to fill listgrid with dynamic columns(column name and number of column can't define from beginning). It's totally dynamic come from db.

How should I fill my listgrid without knowing the name of the field and number of field.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with listgrid in many projects. As per my knowledge I don't think there is a dynamic wayout to add columns in listgrid. But in those condition I have used for loop.

Just take count of fields from database and create for loop. if you do not know the name of column just create it with temp + i as name.

And finally add all fields to listgrid. Even at the time of adding use for loop and max count value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ListGrid and you want to dynamically add a column, you will have to recreate all the other columns and add the new one and then listGrid.setFields. Like this:

```
List<ListGridField> oldColumns; //here you store the old columns
List<ListGridField> newColumns = new ArrayList<ListGridField>(); //here you store the newColumns
for(ListGridField oldField : oldColumns){
    ListGridField newField = new ListGridField(oldField.getName(), oldField.getTitle());
    newColumns.add(newField);
}
ListGridField field = new ListGridField(newName, newTittle); //Declare the new one
newColumns .add(field);
oldColumns = newColumns;
listGrid.setFields(newColumns); //and your listGrid is updated.
```